StackingClassifier with conjunction with gridsearch
I am attempting to use a GridSearchCV on my stackingClassifier, however I was wondering how the gridsearch operates on the backend given that this a stacking classifier. Does GridSearchCV aggregate the out of fold predictions along with the remaining feature values, in order to optimize hyper parameters? Here's a snippet of my code with dummy variables.
stacked_model = StackingClassifier(estimators= [('Log', Log_model), ('Rf', Random_Forest_model), ('XGBoost', XGBoost_model)], 
                                       final_estimator = LogisticRegression(), cv = tscv)
    
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator= stacked_model, param_grid=param_grid,scoring='neg_log_loss', cv=tscv)


Questions solely about how software works are
off-topic
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you
understand the statistical concepts involved, the
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least
easy to get from the documentation.
